# Spring boot ignores datasource url in application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've discovered that spring boot silently ignores all datasource properties loaded through `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties`.

My `application.yml` contains:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        name: this is not ignored
        url: this is ignored
```

During startup i see line:

```
o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Creating embedded database 'this is not ignored'
```

Debugging shows that `DataSourceProperties` object has not any properties set during call to `getUrl` (debugging also shows that exception is thrown but it is silently ignored because it is not visible in logs).

Url is obvoiusly invalid but database is somehow initialized.

Tested on 1.2.7 version.

What can cause such strange behaviour? How can I debug it further?

Comment: Just did the same with 1.3.0.M5 yesterday and it worked. You might want to give either 1.2.6 or the M5 a try. To see which config files are read and which not you might want to install the Actuator and have a look at the /env endpoint. And try to leave the `name` out of the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to dependencies solved problem.

Problem was caused by Spring Boot autoconfiguration magic - I was not using correct spring boot starter.